# Regular expression to find dollar amounts but not match IP address

Tags: php, regex

I have sections of text that may contain both dollar amounts, that may or may not be prepended with a dollar sign, and IP addresses. I need a regular expression that will identify the dollar amounts but not match portions of the IP addresses.

For example if the text is:

```
12.34 56.78.90.12 34.56
```

My starting attempt was:

```
([1-9]\d*\.\d{2})
```

This is what I want to match, but it matches parts of the  IP addresses. I then tried:

```
[^\.]([1-9]\d*\.\d{2})[^\.]
```

But this was worse on almost all cases.

The regular expression needs to match "12.34" and "34.56", but not "56.78" or "90.12". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is 56.78 not a match?

Comment: Hint: You'll need to use a negative lookahead assertion.

Comment: @Andreas In the example give, 56.78 is part of the longer `56.78.90.12`

Comment: @PatrickQ Sorry, how do you know that?

Comment: Ok I see my misstake. Thanks @Patrick didn't think about the example string

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton OP has "For example if the text is: `12.34 56.78.90.12 34.56`"

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks Patrick, jeez that messes with my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to make sure that there are no dots around your match:

```
(?<!\.)\b[1-9]\d*\.\d{2}\b(?!\.)
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zf72ho/1).

Comment: This answer was very helpful. I refined the requirements and ended with the following: (?<!\.)\b\$?((0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2})(?!\.\d) Thanks a ton! (sorry, formatting doesn't survive in comments)

Comment: @Michael: Great to hear it. By the way, text placed between backticks will also be formatted as code within comments.

Comment: The first word boundary in your pattern decreases step count, so it should stay.  However, the second word boundary increases step count and offers no accuracy improvement.  That should removed, right? or can you show me an example where it is required for accuracy purposes?

Comment: Just an added precaution to avoid matching numbers with more than two digits in the decimal fraction.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach different to REGEX assuming there is a space between each element `(dollar amount or ip address)` would be to explode the element by space and get a list of the elements that has only one dot.

```
$text = "12.34 56.78.90.12 34.56";

$dollars_amt = array_filter(explode(' ', $text), function($s) {
    if (substr_count($s, '.') == 1) {
        return $s;
    }
});

print_r($dollars_amt);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => 12.34 [2] => 34.56 )
```

Comment: I was just thinking of a solution like this and when I updated the page I see you already posted it.

Comment: This is a possibility but I'm using regex because the text isn't simply dollar amounts and IP's, there's other general text in there as well. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=^|[^\d.])\d+\.\d+(?=[^\d.]|$)
```

It's basically trying to match this:

```
\d+\.\d+
```

when either the start of the string (`^`) or something not a digit or a dot (`[^\d.]`) is behind it and either the end of the string (`$`) or something not a digit or a dot (`[^\d.]`) is after it.

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/6IZqmg/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using a disqualifying `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` pattern will perform more than twice as fast as the other regex pattern currently posted.

```
/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\$?[1-9]\d*\.\d{2}/
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- IP address   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- currency amount
```

This will first seek and disqualify IP addresses before trying to match your currency values with optional leading dollar sign.  This pattern allows you to match your dollar amounts without using a capture group -- this will improve performance and reduce output array bloat from `preg_match_all()`

[Pattern Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/lsVoqW/1)

Code: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f56fec2d953a1a33115eae31f9ea24be9522653c))

```
$string='12.34 56.78.90.12 34.56 156.8.90.2 $99999.99';
var_export(preg_match_all('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\$?[1-9]\d*\.\d{2}/',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '12.34',
  1 => '34.56',
  2 => '$99999.99',
)
```